# how to make 100 gmail accounts

Tags: android, gmail, google-play

I would like to distribute an app already installed on a tablet. This is a single-purpose app. To get access to Google Play each tablet needs a Gmail account.
Is it a problem to always use the same gmail account?
How can I make a lot of gmail accounts?

Comment: as this question is more operations-related, i would suggest moving it to superuser or serverfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same account on every device. I work for a company that makes apps and we have a test department with dozens of devices all logged in with the same gmail account.

Comment: Using `account+<something>@gmail.com` could be nice. Noting that `<something>` can be *anything* and it's always routed to `account@gmail.com`. Could be some device ID, for instance.